Stack Error with massive stack of nonsense
I am getting the following error when I am trying to run flutter run to windows. Following is the stack:

C:\Users\IT\OneDrive - European Pilot Academy\Desktop\Software\epamarketingapp\windows\flutter\ephemeral.plugin_symlinks\cloud_firestore\windows\cloud_firestore_plugin.cpp(1576,1): error C2248: 'cloud_firestore_windows::PigeonDocumentSnapshot::ToEncodableList': cannot access private member declared in class 'cloud_firestore_windows::PigeonDocumentSnapshot' [C:\Users\IT\OneDrive - European Pilot Academy\Desktop\Software\epamarketingapp\build\windows\x64\plugins\cloud_firestore\cloud_firestore_plugin.vcxproj]
C:\Users\IT\OneDrive - European Pilot Academy\Desktop\Software\epamarketingapp\windows\flutter\ephemeral.plugin_symlinks\cloud_firestore\windows\cloud_firestore_plugin.cpp(1585,1): error C2248: 'cloud_firestore_windows::PigeonDocumentChange::ToEncodableList': cannot access private member declared in class 'cloud_firestore_windows::PigeonDocumentChange' [C:\Users\IT\OneDrive - European Pilot Academy\Desktop\Software\epamarketingapp\build\windows\x64\plugins\cloud_firestore\cloud_firestore_plugin.vcxproj]
C:\Users\IT\OneDrive - European Pilot Academy\Desktop\Software\epamarketingapp\windows\flutter\ephemeral.plugin_symlinks\cloud_firestore\windows\cloud_firestore_plugin.cpp(1591,1): error C2248: 'cloud_firestore_windows::PigeonSnapshotMetadata::ToEncodableList': cannot access private member declared in class 'cloud_firestore_windows::PigeonSnapshotMetadata' [C:\Users\IT\OneDrive - European Pilot Academy\Desktop\Software\epamarketingapp\build\windows\x64\plugins\cloud_firestore\cloud_firestore_plugin.vcxproj]
C:\Users\IT\OneDrive - European Pilot Academy\Desktop\Software\epamarketingapp\windows\flutter\ephemeral.plugin_symlinks\cloud_firestore\windows\cloud_firestore_plugin.cpp(1683,1): error C2248: 'cloud_firestore_windows::PigeonDocumentSnapshot::ToEncodableList': cannot access private member declared in class 'cloud_firestore_windows::PigeonDocumentSnapshot' [C:\Users\IT\OneDrive - European Pilot Academy\Desktop\Software\epamarketingapp\build\windows\x64\plugins\cloud_firestore\cloud_firestore_plugin.vcxproj]
C:\Users\IT\OneDrive - European Pilot Academy\Desktop\Software\epamarketingapp\windows\flutter\ephemeral.plugin_symlinks\cloud_firestore\windows\messages.g.cpp(2293,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:\Users\IT\OneDrive - European Pilot Academy\Desktop\Software\epamarketingapp\build\windows\x64\plugins\cloud_firestore\cloud_firestore_plugin.vcxproj]
ssing ';' before '&' [C:\Users\IT\OneDrive - European Pilot Academy\Desktop\Software\epamarketingapp\build\windows\x64\plugins\cloud_firestore\cloud_firestore_plugin.vcxproj]
C:\Users\IT\OneDrive - European Pilot Academy\Desktop\Software\epamarketingapp\windows\flutter\ephemeral.plugin_symlinks\cloud_firestore\windows\messages.g.cpp(2293,58): error C2065: 'request_arg': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\IT\OneDrive - European Pilot Academy\Desktop\Software\epamarketingapp\build\windows\x64\plugins\cloud_firestore\cloud_firestore_plugin.vcxproj]
C:\Users\IT\OneDrive - European Pilot Academy\Desktop\Software\epamarketingapp\windows\flutter\ephemeral.plugin_symlinks\cloud_firestore\windows\messages.g.cpp(2295,23): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'encodable_request_arg' [C:\Users\IT\OneDrive - European Pilot Academy\Desktop\Software\epamarketingapp\build\windows\x64\plugins\cloud_firestore\cloud_firestore_plugin.vcxproj]
C:\Users\IT\OneDrive - European Pilot Academy\Desktop\Software\epamarketingapp\windows\flutter\ephemeral.plugin_symlinks\cloud_firestore\windows\messages.g.cpp(2297,28): error C2065: 'request_arg': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\IT\OneDrive - European Pilot Academy\Desktop\Software\epamarketingapp\build\windows\x64\plugins\cloud_firestore\cloud_firestore_plugin.vcxproj]

Following is the pubspec.yaml file:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  excel: ^4.0.3
  cloud_firestore: ^5.0.2
  path: ^1.9.0
  firebase_core: ^3.1.1
  url_launcher: ^6.2.5
  uni_links: ^0.5.1
  get_ip_address: ^0.0.7
  firebase_auth: ^5.1.2```


I have tried to change the firebase core and firestore versions but to no avail. I have also tried to recreate the app and moved the lib file to a new app but same problem. 

